# What are the priorities for substituent groups on a cyclohexane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, cyclohexane

I was wondering about this specific scenario:
If you have a cyclohexane, for example, and the cyclohexane has two consecutive substituent groups, for example a methyl group and an ethyl group, how do you decide where the numbering starts?
Would it be 1-ethyl-2-methylcyclohexane or would it be 2-ethyl-1-methylcyclohexane?
Whoever answers this, could you just give some sort of general rules on what to do in this situation (e.g. does it follow alphabetical order, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the numerical sequence of locants is equivalent, the numbering should be assigned to correspond with alphabetical order. Hence, in your example, correct would be 1-ethyl-2-methylcyclohexane. Quoting the [IUPAC Blue Book](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/79/r79_36.htm), Rule A-2.4:

> If two or more side chains are in equivalent positions, the one to be assigned the lower number is that cited first in the name.

Comment: Please note that the link http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/79/r79_36.htm leads to obsolete IUPAC recommendations of 1979.